# Failed to load resource: the http://127.0.0.1:55291/favicon.ico Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am new to AngularJS and I am not getting any output in Chrome browser.

However when I ran it through Bracket (Chrome) and after going to the developer tools I got the following error message:

> Failed to load resource: the http://127.0.0.1:55291/favicon.ico Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="gemStore">
    <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags always come first -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="shared/bootstrap-4.0.0-alpha.5-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

    </head>
    <body ng-controller="StoreController as store">
        <!-- Include the AngularJS library -->
    <script src='shared/angular.min.js'></script>
    <script src='js/app.js'></script>
    <div class="product row" ng-hide="store.product.soldOut">
        <h3>
        {{store.product.name}}
        <em class="pull-right">${{store.product.price}}</em>
        </h3>
        <button ng-show="store.product.canPurchase">Add to Cart</button>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
(function() {
    var app = angular.module('gemStore', []);

    app.controller('StoreController', function(){
    this.product = gem;
    });

    var gem = {
    name: 'Azurite',
    price: 110.50,
    canPurchase: true,
    soldOut: true
    };
})();
```

Comment: The inability to load a favicon has nothing to do with the page not rendering.

Comment: Since 'ng-hide' is set to 'true' in Java Script and hence <div class="product row" ng-hide="store.product.soldOut"> section remains hidden on the browser.